# Looking for a partial match between columns in excel, date and filename data

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I am creating a metadata sheet for about 300 or so records. The two columns I am most concerned with getting perfectly matched are DATE (*e.g.*, yyyy-mm-dd format per ISO 8601) and filename (*e.g.*, asdf_v05_i03_yyyy-mm-dd.pdf). I want to make sure that the DATE column's data matches the FILENAME column's date string. I have tried a few different excel functions to return a TRUE or FALSE value in a different column to do the fact-checking for me, but nothing I've tried seems to work. I suspect it may have something to do with how Excel formats dates.

Any suggestions for how I should format my formula?

Example Data (Tab delimited):

```
Date    Filename
1996-01-05  asdf_v17_i01_1996-01-05.pdf
1996-01-12  asdf_v17_i02_1996-01-12.pdf
1996-01-19  asdf_v17_i03_1996-01-19.pdf
1996-01-26  asdf_v17_i04_1996-01-26.pdf
1996-02-02  asdf_v17_i05_1996-02-02.pdf
```

Comment: Are the names of the pdfs that structure always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the naming is always the same on the pdf then you could use the following:

```
=A2=--MID(B2,14,10)
```

[image]

Comment: Terrific! Thank you!

Comment: @Dilettante pleas mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  Click on the green check mark by the answer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the function of the "--" string?

Comment: It turns number that are text into numbers by multiplying it by, -1*-1 @Dilettante  So in this case it is taking text that is a date and turning it into it numeric value.